# Getting pointer to the current translation table on MIPS (Linux)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, mips, paging, tlb

Long story short: I'd like to get the pointer to the current process' first level translation table on MIPS.

On x86 I get it from CR3. On ARM I use [TTBR](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0433b/CIHFDBEJ.html) for this purpose. How to do this on MIPS (without accessing current `task_struct->mm->pgd`)?

Here is some elaboration on why I need it.

I have to get some info on the current process in Linux running in QEMU system emulator. My code runs on the host, as a part of QEMU. Lets assume that I know all the relevant offsets in the guest kernel structures.

When the guest is in kernel mode (if it's not a kernel thread), it is possible to get the current `task_struct` directly, via `thread_info` that is located on the kernel stack.

However, when the guest is in user mode, I have to traverse the `task_struct` list, comparing each `task->mm->pgd` (actually the appropriate physical address) to the *current* translation table pointer. The latter is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The PTE base address can be read from the MIPS CP0 Context register (#4).

See chapter 16 of [See MIPS Run](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0120884216): *Low-level Memory Management and the TLB*.

Comment: CP0 least significant byte seems to contain an "asid" (address-space id), but it seems to be unrelated to `mm->pgd` (or at least I can't see how to derive one from another). However, I found that struct `mm` contains this asid in some other field, which opens some perspective...